# How can I debug a console .NET Core project in VS Code in a sln?

Tags: c#, debugging, cmd, .net-core, visual-studio-code

How can I debug a console .NET Core project in VS Code in a sln?

I created a solution with the help of the `dotnet new sln`, then I created a few projects and added all of them to the solution be using the `dotnet sln add <PATH TO .csproj>`. All of that I did with the help of VS Code and the git bash.

Now I created a .NET console project with the help of the `dotnet new console`. And I would like to debug it.

I can only run the `dotnet run` in the git bash when the git bash`s current directory in the .NET console project directory and there is nothing like the `dotnet debug`.

[image]

Comment: Have you created a `launch.json`?

Comment: @panoskarajohn, no I did not.

Comment: `vscode` needs two files `tasks.json` and `launch.json`. Create a new `console app` and go to the debugger of vscode. It should have an option to create one for you automatically. See this example there and adapt to your own.